# Arranging Columns in a Matix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this matrix 
[image]

and this matrix [image]

how can I join those matrixes to one matrix where first column from 1 is the first column and the first column from the second matrix is the 2nd column and the second column from matrix 1 is the third and so on

Comment: The final result should be some thing like [![enter image description here][3]][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpueW.png

Comment: Please don't provide images of your Mathematica output -- provide code so that people can work with it to help you.

Comment: the code 
LL = {{50, 50}, {10, 100}, {150, 20}, {450, 350}, {720, 80}, {890, 
   105}, {125, 650}, {190, 780}, {25, 920}, {55, 100}, {700, 
   150}, {500, 500}} //TableForm 

n = Length[LL]

Distancem = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];

Do[Distancem[[i, j]] = 
     Sqrt[(L[[i, 1]] - L[[j, 1]])^2 + (L[[i, 2]] - L[[j, 2]])^2], {i, 
     1, n}, {j, 1, n}] Distancem // MatrixForm;

dist1 = N[Distancem, 4] // TableForm
ddp = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 5, 8}, {k, 9, 12}] // TableForm

Comment: Table[N[Distancem[[i, j]] + Distancem[[j, k]] + Distancem[[k, i]], 
   5], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 5, 8}, {k, 9, 12}] // MatrixForm

Comment: Edit the question with your code placed in code blocks. Code in Comments isn't formatted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not include [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) or [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html) in your definitions. Use parentheses to isolate the definitions from the wrappers.

```
(LL = {{50, 50}, {10, 100}, {150, 20}, {450, 350}, {720, 80}, {890, 
     105}, {125, 650}, {190, 780}, {25, 920}, {55, 100}, {700, 150}, {500, 
     500}}) // TableForm
```

[image]

```
n = Length[LL]

(*  12  *)

 Distancem = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];

Do[Distancem[[i, j]] = 
  Sqrt[(LL[[i, 1]] - LL[[j, 1]])^2 + (LL[[i, 2]] - LL[[j, 2]])^2], {i, 1, 
  n}, {j, 1, n}] 

Distancem // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(dist1 = N[Distancem, 4]) // TableForm
```

[image]

```
(ddp = Table[
    {i, j, k}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 5, 8}, {k, 9, 12}]) //
 TableForm
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  Added code (corrected) from second comment

```
(Table[{i, j, k, 
    N[Distancem[[i, j]] + Distancem[[j, k]] + Distancem[[k, i]], 
     5]}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 5, 8}, {k, 9, 12}]) // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: where is the final table or matrix which is a concatenation of the two tables  distance and the triangular paths?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpueW.png this is what should be as final result sorry I m not familiar with the code blocks

Comment: what if i wanted to   Sort by perimeter the list of triangles with corresponding perimeters.
 Remove from the list the triangles using power stations in the triangle of minimal perimeter to
form the list t and place the minimal triangle with perimeter at the top of the list t.
Repeat step 2 until only the s/3 minimal triangles with perimeters appear in the list p.
In the same graphic draw the s/3 minimal triangles.

Comment: I suggest you post your question.

Comment: the system wont allow me

Comment: Use the `help` menu above to go to the `Help Center`

Comment: I have reached my  question limit